# Point events for Sankey charts?

Tags: anychart

I am working with AnyChart Sankey charts, and trying to to get information for a particular clicked flow or node (i.e. the from and to nodes if a flow is clicked, or the node name if a node is clicked) in the Sankey chart which I need for a specific drilldown function. This is easily doable for other charts using `pointClick`.

Getting `pointClick` events on other charts is quite straight forward using `chart.listen('pointClick', function(e) {});`.

This, however doesn't work on Sankey charts. The `pointClick` event is never registered.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do for Sankey charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the library v8.8.0 (summer 2020) doesn't `pointClick` event due to the specific architecture of the chart. But there's a workaround that implements the required interactivity. For details, check [the sample of a Sankey with custom interactivity](https://playground.anychart.com/uVjSy274/0).